# Trouble deploying database from VS2008 to SQL2005

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, deployment

We are using VS2008 deployment for our databases [database solutions in VS where each one has their own schema.]
The script it produces does not work quite well. "Before deployment it compares the server objects and then creates the script" is the way msdn is telling, but obviously it tries to create objects those exist, or tries to drop the xml schema before dropping the dependent sprocs/tables.
Am I doing something wrong with deployment options, or is this a know bug I am not aware. Any comments?

Answer (score 1):

1) The VS deployment tool always tries to create all objects that exist in the [model] database. It would never tell you that, but it does. I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why it was trying to create a login that I specifically removed from the DB project.
2) Like you said, it sometimes tries to create/drop objects in the wrong order. I usually have it generate the deploy script, but not deploy, and review it by hand.